# Date keeps going back to UTC versus staying formatted in the locale it is in

Tags: swift, date, timezone, utc, dateformatter

I have converted a date/time from UTC to the proper locale timezone, however when I go to create the notification it keeps reverting to the UTC time.

Here is my latest attempt to fix this but it isn't fixing the issue:

```
let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      var components = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: newDate!)
           print(components)

      // Change the time to locale
      formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
      formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
      let date = gregorian.date(from: components)!
```

If I check the value of date, the time is back to UTC +0000

Here is the remainder of the code:

```
      let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second,], from: date)
      print(triggerDaily)
      let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)
```

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

[Update]
After reading the below comments I made the following change:

```
         formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
         formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
         let myDate = formatter.string(from: date)

         let newDate = formatter.date(from: myDate)
```

It is now working as I expected it to.

Comment: FYI newDate! is coming in formatted correctly.

Comment: A date has no locale and or timezone. It is just a point in time. Only its description contains a timezone. All dates are stored and printed using the number of seconds since reference date January 01, 2001 UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "If I check the value of date, the time is back to UTC +0000"

That statement makes no sense. Date objects do not have a time zone. They record an instant in time, anywhere on the planet. It's only when you display it that it gets mapped to a particular timezone.

If you try `print(aDate)` for **any** date it will **always** display in UTC.

Try this instead:

```
print(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: aDate, 
    dateStyle: .medium,
    timeStyle: .medium)
```

That will print `aDate` in your local time zone, using date formatting appropriate for your locale.

Comment: I understand what you are saying; I have been needing to store it in the locale it is at.  I made a few changes and it's working.  I have added my changes above.